# Is the mind's adaptation to increased traveling speeds, physical or psychological?

Tags: perception, cognitive-neuroscience

When a motor vehicle increases in speed, we soon adjust to the faster pace of movement; seemingly by processing incoming information faster.

Is this purely psychological, with the brain "dropping" peripheral information to catch up with the flow of new information? Or does the brain actually put more physical energy (kilojoules) into the task, like muscles using more energy during exercise?

Or put another away - do we simply think we are processing more information or are we actually doing so?

I imagine this distinction would be relevant for fighter pilots and competitive racers.

Comment: I think this is an interesting question, but I would suggest rephrasing since I think the dichotomy between physical and psychological is a false one. Psychological effects are going to have physical underpinnings, though the level of analysis for a question about psychology is often far more abstract than questions about 'physicality'.

Comment: @Josh Feel free to edit the question. I'm a layman in the area of cognitive science. :-)